# What changed between versions of the Amazon Appstore?

Tags: updates, amazon-appstore

The original version of the Amazon Appstore was v1.07002, and it appears to still be working fine, so the upgrade to the new version (v1.07003) is apparently not mandatory (unsuprising, given the tiny version increment).  What is the difference between these two versions?  Is there a release log anywhere?

**Edit:** I believe it's at v1.11 now, feel free to generalize this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.11 (possibly before?), the app itself now contains the changelist.  Just press the Menu button, hit More, hit Settings, and scroll down.

Answer (score 6):

After you posted this I got curious too but I couldn't find a change log.  I emailed Amazon support and asked what changed and where I could find a release log and here's what they said:

> Unfortunately we do not have a change
>   log detailing the changes made between
>   versions of the Amazon Appstore app.
>
> I will forward your feedback on to the
>   Appstore team who will take them into
>   consideration. Customer feedback like
>   yours is what allows us to continue to
>   improve and provide a quality product
>   and experience.
>
> If you have any other feedback please
>   let us know via email or at
>   1-866-749-7771
>
> Thanks for contacting Amazon.

This is actually the most direct answer I've gotten.  I've emailed them a couple other questions and got boilerplate responses that looked like they were for different questions.

Comment: Google should make it mandatory to publish a change log for each and every change in version number. I, for one, am always interested to see what changes have been made between versions. All too often, you update a program to a new version without knowing why the hell they made one.

Comment: I agree but that won't help with the Amazon Appstore app which is distributed outside the Google Market.  The ironic thing is that apps in the Amazon appstore have changelogs, but the Amazon appstore app itself does not.

Comment: their response to you is probably going to get into their database of boilerplates responses, at least until they have a changelog :-)